# Copy all elements from one object except those with that share their key with an element in another object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two objects:

```
obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
}
```

and

```
obj2 = {
  a: "foo",
  c: "bar"
}
```

From those I want to create a third object:

```
obj3 = {
  b: 2,
  d: 4
}
```

The third object should contain all elements from the first object, except those that share their key with an element in the second object.

---

I know ways to achieve this if the excluded keys are hard coded:

```
const { a, c, ...obj3 } = obj1;
```

or

```
const obj3 = Object.assign({}, obj1);
[ "a", "c" ].forEach(key => delete obj3[key]);
```

---

**Is there a way to do this if the excluded keys are not hard coded but instead also keys of another object, like I described above?**

---

*The reason I need to do this is because in my react app I want to spread all props given to a container component to it's child component, except the props defined in the container component's `PropTypes` (the props used by the container component that shouldn't be passed on).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last example is a good start. You can combine it with `Object.keys` to achieve what you want:

```js
let obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
}

let obj2 = {
  a: "foo",
  c: "bar"
}

const obj3 = Object.assign({}, obj1);
Object.keys(obj2).forEach(key => delete obj3[key]);

console.log(obj3);
```

`Object.keys` applied to an object returns a string array containing the keys of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the keys of the first object `obj1` and check whether the key is present in `obj2`, if not present in both `obj1` and `obj2` add it to the third `obj3`.

```js
let obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
}

let obj2 = {
  a: "foo",
  c: "bar"
}
let obj3 = {}; 
Object.keys(obj1).forEach((key)=>{ if(!(key in obj2)){ 
  obj3[key] = obj1[key];
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) to construct a new object from all the keys of `obj1` that don't exist on `obj2`:

```js
const objectDiff = (o1, o2) => 
  Object.entries(o1) // get an array of key/value pairs
  .reduce((r, [k, v]) => ({
    ...r, // add the previous state of the object
    ...k in o2 || { [k]: v } // if key is not in the 2nd object add it
  }), {});
  
const obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
}

const obj2 = {
  a: "foo",
  c: "bar"
}

const result = objectDiff(obj1, obj2);
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1**: using `Object.keys`:

```
const obj4 = Object.assign({}, obj1);
Object.keys(obj2).forEach(key => delete obj4[key]);
```

**Approach 2**: *Another cleaner way*, using `for in` loop with `hasOwnProperty`:

```
function filterKeys(obj1, obj2) {
  const returnObj = {};
  for (const prop in obj1) {
    if (obj1.hasOwnProperty(prop) && !obj2.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      console.log(`obj1.${prop} = ${obj1[prop]}`);
      returnObj[prop] = obj1[prop];
    } 
  }
  return returnObj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to achieve the desired output:

```js
const obj1 = {a: 1,b: 2,c: 3,d: 4}

const obj2 = {a: "foo",c: "bar"}

const obj3 = Object.keys(obj1).filter(k => !obj2.hasOwnProperty(k)).reduce((a,e) => (a[e] = obj1[e], a),{});

console.log(obj3);
```

Comment: This won't work if if any of the values in `obj2` is `0` or `""`.